# Calculating the frequency of which a cron job executes

Tags: ruby, linux, scripting, rubygems

I'm in the process of learning ruby and I'm trying to figure out how I would make a simple script that will do the following:

Take a listing of cron jobs in a text file (output of crontab -l) and calculate the frequency at which they will execute over the course of a year.

So, let's say I have the following cron job:

21 23 * * * /some/cron/job/here

I know that this cron job executes at 11:21 pm every day. So, I want the script to tell me how many times in a year this cron job will run. I know that the answer is 365, but I don't know how to do this in ruby to get the same result.

Also, it would need to be able to handle the more complicated ones - such as:

30 */2 * * * /another/cron/job/here

This one runs 30 minutes past every other hour of every day, so I would need the script to be able to tell me how many times this will run in a year as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We can't write the whole program for you; however, if you post a snippet that is causing trouble for you we can help you debug it.

Comment: I don't want anyone to write the whole program for me, as that would defeat the purpose of me trying to learn how to do it. I'm simply looking for a push in the right direction.

Comment: You might want to start by looking at the cron source code and see how they do it.  Just start with the simple cases, caluclate an interval and divide it into a year.  So if it's every monday night at 2 AM, your interval would be 1 week, 1 year divided by 1 week should give you 52 times a year.

Comment: You could also brute force it... Loop across every second of every minute of every hour of every day of every week of every month of the year; for each second, calculate if you should run it. Then add it all up. Inefficient algorithm, but it'll work.

Comment: Gah, yeah, that math portion is what trips me up. I get about right here before my mind goes blank:                                                                              #!/usr/bin/ruby

file = File.new ("file.log", "r")
while (line = file.gets)
  parts = line.split (' ')
  puts "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is kinda a cruddy answer because I just assume the whole thing is well examplified by your question, but you might go about it like this:

```
def rdcron(line)
  (minutes, hours) = (line.scan(/^\S+ \S+/))[0] # complete the regex with the format of the line
  if hours =~ /(.*)\/(\d+)/
    num=$1; dem=$2;
    num=1 if num == "\*"
    hours = Rational(num,dem).to_f
  end
  #...cron format parsing blocks like the above continue here
  minutes * hours # * ...
end
```